# Variable isn't set unless debug.print executed first

Tags: excel, vba

On my sheet, I click a button, the button fires the below Sub. Which is supposed to read the row and col of the clicked button location, then pop up a message box the with the content of a hidden cell on the same row.

When this code executes, the `ipf` variable always remains as the string "initial" unless I add a `debug.print` statement. I can debug.print any of the variables (`ipf`, `row_no`, `col_no`) and the `ipf` variable is set fine.

After I've added debug.print, clicked the relevant button to get the right result, then removed debug.print, it continues to work until I reload the sheet.

I've tried casting as a string in case that is the problem, but I simply do not understand why it's doing this.

Essentially, the sheet is filled with up to three buttons on each row, when one of those buttons is clicked, this code grabs the row and col of the clicked button to pull the value of the cell, which will be one of three strings; "Initial", "Prelim" or "Final". Using that string (in the `ipf` variable) it will fall into one of the cases to pull a string from another cell on that row to show in a message box.

Unless the `debug.print` is there, the `ipf` var is *always* "Initial".

```vb
Public Sub showDefinitionMsgBox()
    Dim obj As Object, _
        row_no As Long, _
        col_no As Long, _
        wsMain As Worksheet 'This is the worksheet were using

    ' Get the row and column of the clicked button
    Set obj = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller)
    row_no = obj.TopLeftCell.row
    col_no = obj.TopLeftCell.column

    ' Grab the name (e.g. INitial, Prelim, Final)
    ' When a button is clicked, we pull the value from the cell under the button.
    ' It will be either "Initial", "Prelim" or "Final"
    Set wsMain = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MainSheet")
    Dim ipf As String
    ipf = CStr(wsMain.Cells(row_no, col_no).Value)

    ' Get the element name
    ' This simply get's a string, which is the name of the row
    Dim element As String
    element = wsMain.Cells(row_no, 12).Value

    ' Withouth this, ipf is _always_ "initial"
    Debug.Print ipf

    ' Pull the text from the dictionary
    ' 13 = init, 14 = prelim, 15 = final
    ' Using the above ipf variable, set the message text as the content
    ' of another cell in the wsMain sheet.
    Dim message As String
    Select Case ipf
        Case "Initial":
            message = wsMain.Cells(row_no, 13).Value
        Case "Prelim":
            message = wsMain.Cells(row_no, 14).Value
        Case "Final":
            message = wsMain.Cells(row_no, 15).Value
        Case Else
            message = "Cannot find that element type:"
    End Select


    ' Show the message box
    ' @TODO: Update this to UserForm for more space
    MsgBox message, vbOKOnly, element
End Sub
```

I expect the value from the correct cell to appear in the msgbox, but I always get the value from the first case, unless I add the debug.print line.

Comment: It would be great if you can provide a [repro].

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. Could you upload your input?

Comment: Watch the locale variables window while you step through your code. Debug print does not set any variables, so the problem lays elsewhere I'm pretty sure. For example, why did you create a class module and what is `wsMain`

Comment: Apologies @AhmedAbdelhameed and @David. I'm not sure I can provide a minimal reproducable example as I can't get this behaviour to show itself without the code looking like this. `clgGlobals` contains getters/setters for sheets, dictionaries and common variables, but in this sub, all it's doing is returning the Worksheet called "MainSheet"

I've updated the post with some more detail and more comments.

Comment: @MikePearce Again, you're unlikely to get a direct solution unless we can reproduce the problem. For example, what if the problem is caused by some code in `clgGlobals` (which we can't see)?

Comment: _"I can't get this behaviour to show itself without the code looking like this"_ What do you mean? Remember that although providing **minimal** code is important, providing code that **reproduces** the problem is far more important. We can compromise a little bit on the **"minimal"** keyword but it's very difficult (impossible in some cases) to figure out the problem without a **reproducible** example. _"I'm not sure I can provide a minimal reproducable example"_ Please read the article linked in my first comment for guidance.

Comment: OK, I removed the globals class and replaced it with `Set wsMain = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MainSheet")`. It now does the same thing, but the problem persists.

Comment: Turns out, I'd left in a line of code in another class which disabled calculations. Re-enabling them solved the issue.